# Ember console doesn't work

Tags: ember.js

I'm following [the guide](http://youtu.be/Ga99hMi7wfY?t=16m46s) in the official website. And it shows me do some model changes in browser console like:

`App.Post.find(1)`

But in my computer it shows[image]

Any idea?

---

here's my [git repo](https://github.com/markson/ember-tutorial-learning) for this test code

Comment: Do you have a variable called App defined? (It's difficult to help when you only post a screenshot).

Comment: @WiredPrairie App is the name of Ember intense, BTW I've update the question added my Git repo, you can check the code,cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are using CoffeeScript which automatically wraps all code in anonymous functions you need to initialize the App variable as window.App to have access to it outside your app.coffee file.

`window.App = Ember.Application.create...`